# How do I save GORM objects with multiple many-to-one relationships?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Let's say I have the following hierarchy of domain classes.

```
class School {
   String name
   static hasMany = [teachers: Teacher, students: Student]
}

class Teacher {
   String name
   static belongsTo = [school: School]
   static hasMany = [students: Student]
}

class Student {
   String name
   static belongsTo = [school: School, teacher: Teacher]
}
```

I tried two different ways to save a school, teacher, and student.

**Attempt 1:**

```
def school = new School(name: "School").save()
def teacher = new Teacher(name: "Teacher", school: school).save()
def student = new Student(name: "Student", school: school, teacher: teacher).save(flush: true)
```

It appears to save properly but when I run:

```
println(school.students*.name)
```

It prints *null*.

So I decided to try a different approach.

**Attempt 2:**

```
def school = new School(name: "School")
def teacher = new Teacher(name: "Teacher")
def student = new Student(name: "Student")
teacher.addToStudents(student)
school.addToStudents(student)
school.addToTeachers(teacher)
school.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
```

Here I tried several combinations of saves and I always got an error about a required field being null.  In this case the error was

> JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "TEACHER_ID"

I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain why my attempts failed and what the proper way to go about creating the data is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def school = new School(name: "School").save(flush: true)
def teacher = new Teacher(name: "Teacher")
school.addToTeachers(teacher)
teacher.save(flush: true)
def student = new Student(name: "Student", teacher: teacher)
school.addToStudents(student)
```

Comment: That gives me the following exception:  JDBCExceptionReporter  - NULL not allowed for column "TEACHER_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into student (id, version, name, school_id, teacher_id) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: but will these instructions save data in a join Table? where in DB "linking data" will be saved?